# Is it safe or acceptable to use Right Click Context Menus in HTML?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, user-interface, web

With the magic of javascript, and as ubiquitous as libraries are these days, I've noticed that it is increasingly easy to create customized "Right Click Context Menus" for websites, and even for specific controls within specific pages.

My question is, is that a safe/acceptable practice? When I went to school we were very discouraged from it, but that was almost 12 years ago. I'm anxious in the ideas from more experienced developers.

This may be a duplicate thread, but I had difficulty finding any others. I am not good at navigating StackOverflow, though, so it is very possible.

Comment: All depends on your requirements. Though I would say if it is a public website where any anonymous user can come visit then I would opt to keep the right-click behave as default because it will be what the user expects

Comment: This may actually be a better fit for [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Though, I'd say it depends on how you describe your project -- as a "*web site, with simple navigation between various documents*" or as a "*web app, which imitates behaviors of desktop applications*." It's probably more fitting with the latter.

Comment: It's all based on the context, if it's a file managing system or an editing tools for instance, it's okay to attach functions to right click, just be sure that it's obvious that to the user what to expect from it. Also don't try to hide any useful function (save as, open,  view source, etc.)  using this method. It's a bad habit and there's always a workaround, so it makes more damage than goodness.

Answer (score 1):

While it is an acceptable practice, you need to take a look at your target audience. Would they expect to get a context menu if you right-click? Most people expect to get the browser context menu when they right-click, and are surprised (sometimes happy) to find a context menu. I've typically seen an "context menu" icon that, when clicked, shows a context menu.

Also, don't forget mobile users. If you have people using your software on a touch surface, such as a smartphone or tablet, there isn't a way to right-click.

Good luck with your development!